# MongoDB replica set with primary only

Tags: mongodb

After version 4.0, MongoDB has introduced the multi-document transactions for replica sets. In order to use the new feature, I have converted the testing instance to a replica set, following the official  [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/).

The end result was a replica set with a primary node, no secondary nodes and no arbiters. 
I would like to know if this architecture has any implications on performance, data integrity, etc... Any help or reference to a similar case is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It is valid to have a single member replica set for the purposes of testing or development. This will allow you to use features which require a replica set deployment (for example, transactions in MongoDB 4.0+ and change streams in MongoDB 3.6+).

The main downsides of a single member deployment are that you don't get any of the usual replica set benefits such as data redundancy and fault tolerance, and cannot test more interesting [read concerns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern/) and [write concerns](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) that might be useful in a production deployment. A replica set member has some expected write overhead as compared to a standalone server because it also has to [maintain a replication oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog).

A production replica set deployment should have a minimum of three members. See [Deploy a replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set) in the MongoDB documentation for full details.